# Using a uniform color palette among different ggplot2 graphs with factor variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, color-palette

I am using ggplot2 to create several plots about the same data. In particular I am interested in plotting observations according to a factor variable with 6 levels ("cluster").

But the plots produced by ggplot2 use different palettes every time!

For example, if I make a bar plot with this formula I get this result (this palette is what I expect to obtain):

```
qplot(cluster, data = data, fill = cluster) + ggtitle("Clusters")
```

[image: Bar chart of the cluster variable]

And if I make a scatter plot and I try to color the observations according to their belonging to a cluster I get this result (notice that the color palette is different):

```
ggplot(data, aes(liens_ratio,RT_ratio)) +
  geom_point(col=data$cluster, size=data$nombre_de_tweet/100+2) +
  geom_smooth() +
  ggtitle("Links - RTs")
```

[image: Scatterplot with observations colored according to their cluster]

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: have a look at `?scale_color_manual`

Comment: also, you should put the color and size arguments inside the `aes` call.

Comment: If I try to set colors inside aes in ggplot, also my glm lines are colored... and the color palette does not change! Same thing for scale_color_manual, it is completely overridden

Comment: and you are sure that you used `geom_point(aes(color = cluster, size = nombre_de_tweet/100+2))`?

Comment: you could also try making a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be certain this will work in your specific case without a reproducible example, but I'm reasonably confident that all you need to do is set your color inside an `aes()` call *within the geom you want to color*. That is,

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = liens_ratio, y = RT_ratio)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = cluster, size = nombre_de_tweet/100+2)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  ggtitle("Links - RTs")
```

If all plots you make use the same data and this basic format, the color palette should be the same regardless of the geom used. Additional elements, such as the line from `geom_smooth()` will not be changed unless they are also explicitly colored.

The palette will just be the default one, of course; to change it look into `scale_color_manual`.

Comment: Thanks, I originally put the aes clause in the global ggplot call and not in the geom_point one, now it works perfectly